# NetSuite Field Sourcing via Summary CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have two custom records.  Rental & Rental Event.  I am trying to source the laest (MAX) status from my Rental Event field back up to the Rental record.  I have a custom field on the Rental record that stored value is unchecked and trying to source from saved search.  Saved Search formula is what I need help with...this is the latest attempt.  The events will be many to one and I am trying to pull the status of the latest event (date created) and source back to the rental record.

CASE WHEN {created} = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM {custrecord_rental_event}) THEN {custrecord_rental_event_status} ELSE 'Available' END

This is a search for the rental event record, I'm thinking I may need to start my search from the Rental record itself.

Sourcing a field value on a parent record based on many (custom record) activities.  Up for suggestions and not tied to this design if there are alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a custom field on the Rental record that stored value is unchecked and trying to source from saved search.

When "Store Value" is unchecked on a custom field definition page, the field value is calculated at the time of record load, and not persisted to the database.  Therefore these fields are not available to saved searches.  One workaround for this is to create another field with "Store Value" checked, and use a workflow or script to update this from the dynamic field.